# EditText field missing methods

Tags: android, android-edittext

I ran across this response in another question:

> If you check the docs for EditText, you'll find a setText() method. It takes in a String and a TextView.BufferType.

If so, then after adding an EditText widgit and specifying

```
final EditText TextAdd=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAdd);
```

When I try to use `setText()` the only options I have for **TextAdd.** are:

```
`equals(Object o)`
`getClose()`
`hashCode()`
`notify()`
`notifyAll()`
`toString()`
`wait()`
```

Why am I not allowed the `setText()` not any other methods?  What am I missing here?

[EDIT]
Thank you,  user1199931, I'm used to sites that don't allow edits shortly after.

Here's the code I'm using. I've changed **TextAdd** to **txtAnswer**...

```
package com.example.add;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Add<EditText> extends Activity 
{
    Button buttonAdd ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add);

        final EditText txtAnswer=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAnswer);
        buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    // Error line
            txtAnswer.  // Here I have no option for setText()
                }
            }
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Post the code you're trying to run and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't putting parentheses.

`((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextAdd)).setText();`

Comment: Sorry, misinformation given.  The "final" line is to define TextAdd. Later in the program I want to use TextAdd.setText() and I don't have that option. I get the error "The method setText() is undefined for the type EditText"

Comment: That doesn't make much sense.  Those methods you listed in your question are methods of the `Object` class.  In other words they apply to every object.  Are you not using a class variable and trying to access TextAdd in another function?

Comment: Good Question. I'll post the .java

Comment: Looks like I can't post the code in comments and can't post an answer, so I'll start a new question...